# Empty sym array and double array not the same in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I use matlab R2018b
These code are right:

```
a=0.336;
Ta=9.476;
Te=1.208;
Tw=1.498;
eqh=[0.661;0.619;0.568];
ex=[-1.24;-1.346;-1.441];
en=-ex;
ey=[0.376;0.705;0.968];
eqx=[-0.309;-0.357;-0.392];
eh=[1.594;1.583;1.545];
eyqh=[0.642;0.78;0.897];
a0=a*Ta*Te^2;
syms bt Td Ki Kp;
a1=[];a2=[];a3=[];a4=[];exqh=[];
for i=1:3
        Kp=1/bt;
        exqh(i)=en(i)*eqh(i)+eqx(i)*eh(i);
        Ki=1/(bt*Td);
        a1=Ta*Tw*eqh(i)+a*Te^2*en(i)+a*Te^2*ey(i)*Kp
        a1(i)=a1
end
```

But these code are wrong:

```
a=0.336;
Ta=9.476;
Te=1.208;
Tw=1.498;
eqh=[0.661;0.619;0.568];
ex=[-1.24;-1.346;-1.441];
en=-ex;
ey=[0.376;0.705;0.968];
eqx=[-0.309;-0.357;-0.392];
eh=[1.594;1.583;1.545];
eyqh=[0.642;0.78;0.897];
a0=a*Ta*Te^2;
syms bt Td Ki Kp;
a1=[];a2=[];a3=[];a4=[];exqh=[];
for i=1:3
        Kp=1/bt;
        exqh(i)=en(i)*eqh(i)+eqx(i)*eh(i);
        Ki=1/(bt*Td);
        a1(i)=Ta*Tw*eqh(i)+a*Te^2*en(i)+a*Te^2*ey(i)*Kp

end
```

The difference between them is :

```
a1=Ta*Tw*eqh(i)+a*Te^2*en(i)+a*Te^2*ey(i)*Kp
        a1(i)=a1
```

and

```
 a1(i)=Ta*Tw*eqh(i)+a*Te^2*en(i)+a*Te^2*ey(i)*Kp
```

I do not know why the second is wrong.

```
The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
Unable to convert expression into double array.

Error in Now3 (line 20)
        a1(i)=Ta*Tw*eqh(i)+a*Te^2*en(i)+a*Te^2*ey(i)*Kp
```

Comment: When you say "it's right" you mean that it doesn't generate an error message. I can't believe it does what you want it to do, because the result of the first two loop iterations are thrown away (overwritten).

Comment: @CrisLuengo The letter 'i' is changed, I tested it in my software, and I did not generate an error.

Comment: Yes, `i` is changed, but `a1` is overwritten, discarding the values it had in the previous loop iteration. When you do `a1=...` you throw away anything that `a1` has previously, and give it a new value. You are discarding the results for `i=1` and `i=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a1 =[];
```

> *is an empty double array*

**while**

```
Ta*Tw*eqh(i)+a*Te^2*en(i)+a*Te^2*ey(i)*Kp;
```

> *is a sym variable, can't be assigned directly to a double array*

**Alternative**

```
a1 = sym([]);
```

> *is an empty sym  array*

Comment: Ta*Tw*eqh(i)+a*Te^2*en(i)+a*Te^2*ey(i)*Kp;  is a sym variable. Why can it be assigned to a1 which should be double because a1=[] is an empty double array?

Comment: But why can it be assigned indirectly to a1(1)?

Comment: And can you tell me why a1(1) is a double variale?

Comment: And why a1 is a neutral matlab but a1(1) is a  double variable?

Comment: @Y.zeng: `a1 = ...` overwrites `a1`, its previous value and type are irrelevant. `a1(1) = ...` assigns something **into** the array `a1`, its type is relevant.

Comment: @CrisLuengo If I put Ta*Tw*eqh(i)+a*Te^2*en(i)+a*Te^2*ey(i)*Kp to a1, then I put a1 to a1(1), what is the difference to I putting Ta*Tw*eqh(i)+a*Te^2*en(i)+a*Te^2*ey(i)*Kp to a1(1) directly?

Comment: @Y.zeng: Please read my previous comment again. I explain exactly what the difference is.